# Why isn't this code changing the variable to True Or False

Tags: lua, roblox

## Problem

So currently, I am making a game in Roblox. I am working on tweening one of my GUIs, but the code isn't changing the var I am working with called `state`. The state var is supposed to tell if it's open or closed (State would = true if open, else, State would = false).

I have tried to make the variable a local var. But still the same output. I checked the output by printing the `state` var. Which would always be the same as the default value.

## Code

```
-- Local Variables
local Frame = script.Parent.Parent.Parent.Parent.Parent.MinerGuiManager.MinerFrame
State = false
local Button = script.Parent.Button


-- Open/Close Statements

if State == true then
    Button.Text = 'Close!'
    script.Parent.Button.MouseButton1Click:connect(function()
    Frame:TweenPosition(UDim2.new(0.3,0,1.2,0))
    State = false
end)
end

if State == false then
    Button.Text = 'Open!'
    script.Parent.Button.MouseButton1Click:connect(function()
    Frame:TweenPosition(UDim2.new(0.305,0,0.25,0,'Bounce',1.5))
    State = true
end)
end
```

I expect the output of the code to set the var `state` to be True when open and False when closed.

Comment: Lua variables are case-sensitive, in your edit, you put in `state` instead of `State` - This does not resolve your issue though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to be careful about how you connect your Mouse1Click event listeners.

When you read your script from top to bottom, you'll see that since `State` starts as false, the only listener you've connected is the second one. This means that when you click on the button, it will only ever tween the Frame into the Open state. It is better to write one click handler that handles this logic on every click.

```
local Button = script.Parent.Button
local Frame = script.Parent.Parent.Parent.Parent.Parent.MinerGuiManager.MinerFrame
State = false

Button.MouseButton1Click:connect(function()
    if State == true then
        Button.Text = 'Close!'
        Frame:TweenPosition(UDim2.new(0.3,0,1.2,0))
    else
        Button.Text = 'Open!'
        Frame:TweenPosition(UDim2.new(0.305,0,0.25,0,'Bounce',1.5))
    end)

   State = not State
end)
```

Comment: When I put it into Roblox, Roblox outputs an error, that says ``` Expected Identifier got')' ``` This shows up at the ```end)```.

Comment: Sorry for the typo. I forgot to close the connect function. Will update the answer

Answer (score 1):

You are missing `State = false` after `Frame:TweenPosition(UDim2.new(0.3,0,1.2,0))` line. You never switch its value back to `false` after it was changed to `true`.

Comment: You added a different variable (`state`) instead of the one you are using in other places (`State`).